# PySpark: Iterations over dict type RDD

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

I have a dict type RDD with me:

```
>>> a.collect()
```

> [{(1155718, 105): 14, (1155718, 1887): 2, (1155718, 1930): 12,
>   (1155718, 927): 6, (1155718, 2783): 8, (1155718, 738): 4, (1155718,
>   952): 4, (1155718, 1196): 6, (1155718, 997): 4, (1155718, 2904): 38}]

Just to check:

```
>>> a.map(lambda x:type(x)).collect()
```

> [< type 'dict' >]

However I am not able to iterate over dict type RDD using `map()`. I tried:

```
>>> a.map(lambda x:(k,v) for k,v in x.iteritems())
```

To my utter surprise it results in error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'x' is not defined
```

Am I missing any important point here.

EDIT: code is all right barring small bug related to generator syntax correct code should be:

```
a.map(lambda x:[(k,v) for k,v in x.iteritems()])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried this :

```
data = [{(1155718, 105): 14, (1155718, 1887): 2, (1155718, 1930): 12, (1155718, 927): 6, (1155718, 2783): 8, (1155718, 738): 4, 
         (1155718, 952): 4, (1155718, 1196): 6, (1155718, 997): 4, (1155718, 2904): 38}]

rdd = sc.parallelize(data) 
rdd.flatMap(lambda _: [(k,v) for (k,v) in _.items()]).collect()
```

and got this :

```
[((1155718, 105), 14),
 ((1155718, 738), 4),
 ((1155718, 2904), 38),
 ((1155718, 1887), 2),
 ((1155718, 1196), 6),
 ((1155718, 1930), 12),
 ((1155718, 927), 6),
 ((1155718, 2783), 8),
 ((1155718, 997), 4),
 ((1155718, 952), 4)]
```

Comment: You are right actually my code should be `a.map(lambda x: [(k,v) for k,v in x.iteritems()])`

Comment: Just to note here: for Python 3, using `items()`. For Python 2, using  `iteritems()`